# How to detect remote actor disconnection (dissociation)?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have server that contains some ServerActor.
That actor receives RegisterClient messages and adds ActorRefs to list of registered clients.

I also have multiple clients, each of them contains ClientActor that should be registrered on server for further actions.

What is the best pattern to handle client actor disconnect (because of network failure for example). Should I implement some hearbeat messages or akka.net contains something like this out of the box?

Comment: It seems like I found answer by myself:
http://getakka.net/docs/remoting/deathwatch

Comment: yep, that's correct - post this as the answer to your question and mark it as accepted so other people who have this question can find it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka.net documentation contains answer for that question: [Detecting and Handling Network Failures with Remote DeathWatch](http://getakka.net/docs/remoting/deathwatch)